# Getting exit code out of docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exit, exit-code, terminate

I have an issue getting an exit code out of `docker-compose up`.
I have the simplest container that runs a script that always exits with 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
exit 1
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  test_container:
    container_name: test_container
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/run.sh:/app/run.sh
    entrypoint: ["/app/run.sh"]
```

When I run it with:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --force-recreate test_container
```

I can see in logs:

```
Recreating test_container ... 
Recreating test_container ... done
Attaching to test_container
test_container exited with code 1
```

But when I `echo $?`, I get `0`.
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4. Running on OSX 10.12.6.
Am I doing something wrong? Is that a known issue (I couldn't find anything out there)?

Comment: I don't see the reason to get back `1` since `docker-compose` has run successfully.

Comment: `docker-compose run/exec` do return exit codes of the container being run

Comment: I believe this is because you define a specific container with `exec` and `run`. But with `docker compose up` you may have a collection of containers. For example, if you had another `test_container_2` at your case exiting with `0`, what would you expect to get from `echo $?` then?

Comment: Why don't you try to get the exit code of your container with `docker inspect`?

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to do that

Answer (score 15):

An option `--exit-code-from SERVICE` can be used with docker-compose up :)

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/):

```
docker compose up

Options:
    --exit-code-from SERVICE   Return the exit code of the selected service container.
                               Implies --abort-on-container-exit.

    --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was stopped.
                               Incompatible with -d.

    -d                         Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names.
                               Incompatible with --abort-on-container-exit.
```

Comment: Nice! I added some info from the docs, which I think should be mentioned...

Comment: "--exit-code-from SERVICE" isn't too clear so i tested it really quick. it will return the actual exit code if you have the service that failed directly but if not, it returns a SIGTERM (128)